# Does this JavaScriptCore question belong on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

Yesterday this question was asked: [JavaScriptCore nested “call” performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27568249/1317805). In just 24 hours it's received 40 up votes, but has yet to receive an answer. In fact, it's the most voted [javascriptcore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascriptcore) question by more than three times, with the second highest-rated question in that tag only having 12 up votes. It's also the highest-voted unanswered [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) question by almost double, too.

Buried deep within the question, we find what is actually being asked:

> I'm trying to better understand this behavior. My question is whether anyone has insight into this. Is this known behavior that should be avoided? Is it fair to consider this a performance defect?

This appears to be asking three questions. The latter two I'd vote to close as *Primarily Opinion-based*, but the first is somewhat on topic. Regardless, I have voted to close the question.

However the whole thing seems to be one big bug report. The reason I'm posting this here on Meta is because even if this is closed, I'm very curious as to just how this received 40 up votes with nobody other than myself voting to close it.

If anything I get the feeling the user may have been instructed to use the [javascriptcore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascriptcore) tag here on Stack Overflow for the entire purpose of raising a bug report. Furthermore I also get the feeling the majority of the 40 up voters are potentially visiting the question from an external site related to JavaScriptCore bugs - although I have no proof of this and it's mere speculation.

Does this question belong here?

Comment: The post isn't linked from the bug report filed at Apple. (Seems like someone reddited the Q a few minutes ago though.)

Comment: @Mat Google works fast! I actually linked to it on Reddit a few minutes ago as I do think it's an interesting issue. Speaking to a couple of people in the JavaScript chat room, they do believe it to be on topic and not opinion-based. I feel that this has somehow slipped through the net though. It's worded in such a way that makes people feel like it shouldn't be closed, perhaps.

Comment: The votes came long before you shared it on reddit, no?

Comment: @BoltClock yes, I shared it after posting here.